# Heroku/Django - Cannot find Postgresql db

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

When I am running my server in heroku, I get this error saying:

```
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

On my heroku app, it says that it does have a Postgres db addon added.
[image: See, I do]

DATABASE SETTINGS

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {}
}

try:
    from .local_settings import LOCAL_DATABASE_SETTING

    DATABASES['default'] = LOCAL_DATABASE_SETTING
except ImportError:
    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'heroku-postgresql',
        }
```

Comment: But have you configured Django to use that db? How? Are you using django-heroku or dj-database-url? Show your DATABASES settings.

Comment: Yup, that's correct. Heroku doesn't give you a local database. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you configure the database on Heroku.

Heroku does indeed make it simple; what you have to do is [fully documented](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration#settings-py-changes). But to summarise: install the django-heroku package, and at the end of your settings file call `django_heroku.settings(locals())`. You can then remove the LOCAL_DATABASE_SETTING stuff.

Comment: I added this to the end of settings.py (and read the docs) but it still didn't work.

Comment: Django_heroku also broke it on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at what `django_heroku` [does with `DATABASE_URL`](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/blob/master/django_heroku/core.py#L75), I found that it uses [`dj-database-url`](https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/):

> This simple Django utility <...> returns a Django database connection
>   dictionary, populated with all the data specified in your URL

So I came to this solution:

```
## shell
$ pipenv install dj-database-url

## settings.py
import dj_database_url

# set default value
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
    }
}

# if environment variable present, it must be Heroku
if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ:
    # replace default with parsed value
    DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(ssl_require=True)
```

Hope it helps